# Convert escaped xml into nodes of the current document

Tags: xslt

I am working with a set of interrelated documents that I am collecting with a single XSL and processing (determining the URL to used based on the content and processing done so far).

For example a document is being fetched from with my XSL using:

```
<xsl:for-each select=
"(document('<someURL>')//atom:entry/atom:content/m:properties/d:PresentationContent) 
[position()=1]">
  <xsl:call-template name="formHandler"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is all fine for most documents.

Except that in one case the content of the element `d:PresentationContent` then contains escaped XML directly as text (ie. not using cdata) e.g.

```
&lt;Component&gt;&lt;Id&gt;tcm:10-7788&lt;/Id&gt;&lt;/Component&gt;
```

Is there any way within XSL to fetch the document, convert the encoded strings to XML AND process the nodes as if they are part of the document so that the example can be treated as if it were:

```
//atom:entry/atom:content/m:properties/d:PresentationContent/atom:Component/atom:Id
```

I am already a long way through the solution and this will be very costly for me to change at this stage - so any help very gratefully received. (Backup plan is to construct a http proxy that I make the request through and have the proxy clean the response.)

Comment: *"Is there any way within XSL to fetch the document, convert the encoded strings to XML AND process the nodes as if they are part of the document"* - Without an XSLT extension function? No. With an extenstion, definitely. But then you need to say what processor you are using and the program would not be 100% portable anymore.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, Fundamentally I will use whatever processor will work ;-) . I currently have in my dev environment Saxon6 5.5, Saxon-PE, Saxon-EE, Saxon-HE, JAXP, XALAN. Execution environment is groovy and java based - so if I can load the library into that (and its free!) then I will use it.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 Saxon6 5.5 .

Comment: Well, Saxon 7.4 has [`saxon:parse()`](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.4/extensions.html#parse). Saxon 6.5.5 has no equivalent, but you an always write your own Java function to [extend Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.5/extensibility.html).

Comment: Tomalak, thanks will try saxon:parse() and 7.4. Writing my own extension was option C. If you want to convert this to an answer I will +1 it. Cheers,

Comment: Perhaps you should consider to do the conversion in two steps. 1. Identity transform with output of problematic part with `disable-output-escaping="yes"`. Step 2. normal operation. This should work with any xslt processor

Comment: @hr_117: that isn't correct - not every parser implements DOE because it isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

With **XSLT 3.0** you can use the [`parse-xml()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-parse-xml) function:

```
<xsl:template name="formHandler">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parse-xml(text())/Component/Id" />
</xsl:template>
```

Because the escaped XML does not have any delclared namespaces or namespace-prefix, the elements should be addressed without a namespace.